# Java Play2 - Generic templates?

Tags: java, templates, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

is it possible to create generic templates?

Pseudo code:

```
@(myForm: Form[T])
```

So I can reuse them like this:

```
@inputText(
                myForm("title"), 
                '_label -> "title"

            )
```

- If yes, How do I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the magic underscore for that:

```
@(form: Form[_])
```

This is called an existential type in Scala, it roughly means "there exists a type parameter but I don't care what it is".

Comment: I guess in scala everything is called "magic" :D. Thanks this solved my problem.

Comment: But I do care what the type is! Is there a way to implement `Form[_ extends MyAbstractForm]`?

Answer (score 4):

I don't like the `@(form: Form[_])` approach as it is throws type safety out the window.

When passing in `ok(form.render(userform))`, you'll get no help from the compiler when you `@form("lastNme")` in your template, but you will get a runtime error if not caught during testing.

What I'm doing is supplying an interface (or trait in play 2 scala) for common forms (e.g. membership signup and conference registration, or league stats and team stats, etc.); that way, at compile time, fat fingered typos and the like are caught.

Yes, more boilerplate to deal with, but coming from the dynamic language side of the fence, the less I have to deal with runtime errors the better...

Answer (score 2):

Did you try?

in the `app/views` package create new vies: `pseudo.scala.html`

```
@(someParam: String)
<h1>This is my pseudo template</h1>
<div>And there is some param: <b>@someParam</b></div>
```

Then in any other view you can use it like this:

```
...
<div>@pseudo("param pam pam")</div>
...
```

Of course your param(s) don't need to be `String` only, so you can pass there, `Form[T]`, `List[T]`, or whatever else.

Comment: No I thought something like this:  `@(myForm: Form[T])` and use it in the controller -> `ok(form.render(userform))   or   ok(form.render(commentform))`

Comment: Ach, you want to use Form of any type... Try the Marius' solution then in Scala underscore is some kind of wildcard, like asterisk in other languages.

Comment: It's either a wildcard or it says "I don't care".